# Placement of int for functions

Tags: c, unix

I've been looking over the Illumos source code lately and noticed something odd.

In their source the function types are written like:

```
static int
outdec64(unsigned char *out, 
unsigned char *chr, int num) 
{
 ... Code ... 
}
```

Which is definitely not the way I learned it. Does it have any specific meaning?

Comment: It means the author wanted to keep the lines short for readability on ancient CRTs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all coding style and thus subjective. What's most important when it comes to coding style is that you pick one and stick to it consistently.

Here's some recommendations for coding style, which is ultimately personal opinion, although in this answer my "personal" opinion happens to be what I believe is most common in all C code I have ever read:

---

**Storage class specifier and return type**

The most common style is to put the storage class specifier (and function specifiers such as `inline`) and the return type at the same line as the function name:

```
static int outdec64
```

That's de facto coding style and by far the most common. It also makes the function declaration style consistent with variable decaration style. I would therefore strongly recommend to use that style.

A less common alternative is to split the storage specifier and put it on a line of its own:

```
static 
int outdec64
```

Although less common, there's at least a sound rationale for this style: keep storage specifier separate.

Some people like to put the return type on a line of its own, like in your example. But then they usually haven't given their coding style much thought, because when you mix in storage class specifiers, the code turns weird. The storage specifier `static` doesn't refer to the return type, but to the function as whole. So why write it together with the return type? In my experience, people who use that style are typically oblivious to what the keywords `static`, `extern` and `inline` mean, when written in front of a function.

---

**Function parameters**

Two de facto standard styles exist: all parameters on a single line

```
outdec64 (unsigned char *out, unsigned char *chr, int num)
```

or each parameter on its own line, each of them indented

```
outdec64 (unsigned char *out, 
          unsigned char *chr, 
          int num)
```

These two styles are usually mixed, so that functions with few parameters put them on a single line, while functions with plenty of parameters put them on different lines.

Any other style than these two is rare and therefore questionable.

---

As you can see, your example follows neither of these de facto standards, so at least I would regard it as obscure style.

Comment: Placing storage class specifier and return type on the same line and then a line break makes it easy to find a function definition: Just grep for `^function_name(`.

Comment: @FUZxxl Or you could simply click on the function name in your modern IDE... or you could use the search feature of your modern IDE and type in `function_name` there. Or you could place the cursor on the function's call and use an IDE feature to go directly to the function. And so on. Lots of such fancy stuff was invented in the early 90s. I feel we should no longer adapt our coding style to suit old command prompts...

Comment: Many people (especially UNIX folks) don't develop with an IDE. Personally, I don't use an IDE either and I don't think the Solaris developers use IDEs either. Working on a command prompt is quick, not taxing to your computer and you don't need a mouse which is a good thing if you hate mice (like me).

Comment: @FUZxxl If an IDE is taxing your computer, you are either running Eclipse or your computer is very bad... in either case, upgrade to something that makes you productive instead. And if you hate the mouse, you can always learn all the keyboard shortcuts of an IDE. Anyway, my point is that your coding style should only be concerned about readability and program safety, nothing else. External factors should not be allowed to affect it.

Comment: Style and choice of editors is pretty subjective.  FUZxxl explained why someone might prefer this style; it doesn't seem constructive to argue with people's preferences.

The illumos codebase is both large and widely-used, and I don't think it's constructive to call its style questionable, rare, or obscure.  Besides that, I can promise you that many of the contributors do know quite well what "static" and "extern" mean -- your note about that is purely FUD.

Comment: @DavePacheco Then please explain to me what an `inline int` is, if it is such well-known and sound practice to use that style.

Comment: "inline int" by itself is not a C construct. "inline int foo(void) { ... }" is a definition of a function "foo" that takes no arguments, returns int, and whose instructions should be inlined where the function is logically called. The presence of a newline does not impact the semantics at all. I think you're trying to make an argument about style, but I'm not debating style; I'm claiming only two facts: that this style is used in widely-used codebases (e.g., ZFS and DTrace), and that many people who use it fully understand the underlying C semantics.

Comment: The code in question is in a source base that has a rigorous style guide, programmatic style checker -- and a style that dates back to the dawn of C and Unix.  In particular, the style of placing the return type on a separate line dates to 7th Edition Unix; the notion that "they haven't given their coding style much thought" is entirely ignorant of the history of C and Unix.  Even if it's a style that you personally disagree with, at least show some reverence for the fact that it's the style of the framers of modern computing -- one that happens to live on in illumos.

Comment: @BryanCantrill "...style that dates back to the dawn of C" And that's the root of the problem, it is a style originating from the dark ages where storage class specifiers were barely used for functions, and function specifiers had not yet been invented. What "rigorous style guide" do you refer to? I hope it isn't the "Linux kernel coding style guide", because that one is of very questionable quality and written by some hobbyist.

Answer (score 10):

No, white-space is generally ignored in C. That's just coding style.

Here's the coding style for [SunOS](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~lee/06cse480/data/cstyle.ms.pdf):

> Each function should be preceded by a block comment prologue that gives the name and a short description of what the function does. **The type of the value returned should be alone on a line in column 1** (int should be specified explicitly).

This falls in line with another rule:

> Lines longer than 80 columns are not handled well by all terminals and should be avoided if possible

Comment: Some of the things in that document are good advise, some are seriously obscure style, with no rationale provided... Probably not a good document to read when deciding a style in modern C programming.

Comment: @Lundin So... what things?

Comment: @FUZxxl To answer that, I would have to write a whole essay in this limited comment field.

Comment: @user5292516 Thank you for the pdf. I've been searching for an answer, probably didn't use the right string.